# Heroku - rails app crash logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, crash-reports

I just pushed my code to heroku and the app crashed,  got this log which I fail to understand. Can anybody please help?

```
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block i
n <module:Finisher>'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_i
nitializers'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initialize
rs'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_
missing'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
require'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
block in require'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
require'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `
load_dependency'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (requ
ired)>'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-07-26T14:08:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-07-26T14:08:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-07-26T14:08:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `
block in const_missing'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:59739
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_mi
ssing_constant': Expected /app/app/controllers/users.rb to define Users (LoadError)
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `
each'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `
const_missing'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:212:in `const_missing_fro
m_s3_library'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/users.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
require'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
block in require'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `
load_dependency'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
require'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `
require_or_load'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `
depend_on'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `
require_dependency'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in 
eager_load!'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!
'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
require'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block i
n <module:Finisher>'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
require'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `
block in require'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_
missing'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_i
nitializers'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initialize
rs'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `
load_dependency'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (requ
ired)>'
2012-07-26T14:13:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-07-26T14:13:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-07-26T14:13:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem here : /app/app/controllers/users.rb. I see many problems. In this file you should define the class `Users`. It think you should rename you file like this `users_controller` and define your class like this :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
end
```